# Swift MacOS, how copy original file URL after casting to NSFilePromiseReceiver?

Tags: swift, macos, foundation

I implemented a very basic drag n' drop following the official documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/documents_data_and_pasteboard/supporting_drag_and_drop_through_file_promises

However, I need more than just receiving a file, I would like to save not only the file but the original URL as well, the problem is, when I cast the received object further castings are not possible:

```swift
    open override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {

        guard let pasterboardObjects = sender.draggingPasteboard.readObjects(forClasses: [NSFilePromiseReceiver.self, NSString.self], options: nil), pasterboardObjects.count > 0 else { return false }

        pasterboardObjects.forEach {

            if let filePromiseReceiver = $0 as? NSFilePromiseReceiver {

//                print("file promise receiver", filePromiseReceiver, filePromiseReceiver.)
                filePromiseReceiver.receivePromisedFiles(atDestination: destinationURL, options: [:], operationQueue: workQueue) { _, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("error saving image")
                    } else {
                        print("Image saved to", destinationURL)
                    }
                }
            }

            print("After receiving file", $0)

            if let png = $0 as? NSImage {
                print("image dropped")
            }

            if let url = $0 as? URL {
                print("URL dropped")
            }

            if let string = $0 as? String {
                print("String dropped")
                internalStore?.appendString(string: string)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

How would I go about copying the $0 parameter for it to be catched down the if hierarchy?

Comment: Use the `in` operator to your forEach closure. `.forEach { object in …` instead of the default $0

Comment: @WarrenBurton that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: What do you mean, "further castings are not possible"? Are you getting compilation errors? If you receive a file promise, why do you expect that you've also received an image, URL, or string?

Comment: My intention was besides getting the file promise, also receive the URL of the image (in case it is a linked image for example) but I know see that I'm mistaking the received object has a single type and cannot be further catched by the as? URL casting below

Comment: Is the dragging source your app? Which types are on the pasteboard?

Comment: no, dragging source is safari, besides the pasteboard types I have string and url

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a way to do this, since the data is casted before reaching the forEach loop, I did notice though that the saved image contains extra metadata and that includes the location of the original file, so that *kinda* solves my problem.